# Wordpress get custom fields by metabox ids

Tags: arrays, wordpress, function

I'm registering multiple metaboxes in my write posts panels. In functions.php:

```
$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id' => 'products',
    'title' => 'Products',
    'pages' => array('post', 'page', 'link'), // multiple post types, accept custom post types
    'context' => 'normal', // normal, advanced, side (optional)
    'priority' => 'high', // high, low (optional)
    'fields' => array(
        array(
                        'name' => 'something',
            'id' => $prefix . 'something',
            'desc' => 'some description',
            'type' => 'checkbox'
              ),
                 //continue with other fields
             )
           );

//another metabox 
$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id' => 'customers',
    'title' => 'Customers',
//etc...
```

I'm able to get all the values of fields in a post using:

```
$custom_field_keys = get_post_custom_keys();
foreach ( $custom_field_keys as $key => $value ) {
    $valuet = trim($value);

    if ( '_' == $valuet{0} )
        continue;
        echo $value . ":<br />";
        echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $value, true) . "<br/><br/>";
}
```

How can I get the names and values of all fields within a metabox that I specify. For example get all values of fields in metabox id "products".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my advice is look at how this is represented in the db (probably in postmeta table) and use $[wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) - the wordpress db connection class to query the db using the post id and the meta-box name for the fields name - actually someone already did this, as an extension to meta-box - saw a reference in meta-boxes site.

Comment: Thanks! I looked in the db table and there is no column with a metabox name. Maybe I have to add my own column to make this possible

Comment: It is a known practice in wordpress plugin development to store data like this in an array in options table or somewhere else, probably not a seperate column.  but rest assured IT IS SOMEWHERE IN THE DB.. or it wouldn't exists.. I'm sure it's not hard coded in the plugin. so query/search the whole wordpress db and you'll find the answer